# Microcanonical Ensemle

Tags: statistical-mechanics

The energy of a particle is given by E=|p|+|q|, where p and q are generalized momentum and coordinate respectively. All the states with E less than equal to E0 are equally probable and states with E greater than equal to E0 are inaccessible. What is the probability density of finding the particle at coordinate q with q >0 ?